# overtaking acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

A driver travelling at 50km/hr,trying to overtake another car by pressing an accelerater.The acceleration behaviour of the car is (dv/dt)=1.22-0.015v,whereby v=speed in m/s,calculate
a)maximum speed of the car
b)maximum rate of acceleration
c)the rate at which the car accelerate after 3sec
d)the time it takes to reach a speed of 120km/hr

```
note dv/dt=(q-rv)ex^-rt
```

Comment: Hi Gerald and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1) Maximum speed occurs when the first derivative of velocity with respect to time is zero.

2)For this you will have to differentiate your initial function as the first derivative of velocity is acceleration.

3) For the remaining parts, I suggest that you find an explicit relationship between velocity and time by solving the Differential Equation.(It is variable separable and I reckon it will yield an exponential)